How to find matching date index in multiple dataframes with no use of looping?
I am trying to find matching index for each date inside a multiple dataframes. if a date is found inside a dataframe, then move to next matching date. I am using a loop and it is very slow when dataframe is big. I am looking for a way to make it faster. Thanks for your help.
Here is the way I am doing. It will be slow when dataframe is big and number of time to find is big. Here is just a simple example.
I think using loop is not a good idea. However I have to check if a data is inside a dataframe or not. that is why I have to loop over each date. Thanks.
df_tomatch_1=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[10,20,30,40]})
df_tomatch_1.index=['2023-01-01 10:00','2023-01-01 11:00','2023-01-01 12:00','2023-01-01 13:00']
df_tomatch_1

    a   b
2023-01-01 10:00    1   10
2023-01-01 11:00    2   20
2023-01-01 12:00    3   30
2023-01-01 13:00    4   40

df_tomatch_2=pd.DataFrame({'c':[1,2,3,4],'d':[10,20,30,40]})
df_tomatch_2.index=['2023-01-02 10:00','2023-01-02 11:00','2023-01-02 12:00','2023-01-02 13:00']
df_tomatch_2

    c   d
2023-01-02 10:00    1   10
2023-01-02 11:00    2   20
2023-01-02 12:00    3   30
2023-01-02 13:00    4   4

time_tomatch=['2023-01-01 10:30','2023-01-01 12:30','2023-01-02 11:30']

def find_matched_date_index(df_tomatch_list,time_tomatch):
    indx_time=[]
    for date_str in time_tomatch:
        print(date_str)
        thisdate=pd.to_datetime(date_str)
        # print('this date is',date_str
        for ix_file,df in enumerate(df_tomatch_list):
            df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
            if thisdate>=df.index[0]-timedelta(days=0.01) and thisdate<=df.index[-1]+timedelta(days=0.01):
                indx_found=df.index.get_indexer([thisdate],method='nearest')[0]
                indx_time.append([ix_file,indx_found])
                break   # exit for loop of dataframe
    return indx_time

indx_time=find_matched_date_index([df_tomatch_1,df_tomatch_2],time_tomatch)
print(indx_time)

2023-01-01 10:30
2023-01-01 12:30
2023-01-02 11:30
[[0, 1], [0, 3], [1, 2]]


IIUC, you could (semi) vectorize your code by getting all indices at once and using numpy:
import numpy as np

# get indexer and valid datetimes
mask = np.vstack([idx.between(df.index.min(), df.index.max())
                  for df in df_tomatch_list])
idxs = np.vstack([df.index.get_indexer(time_tomatch, method='nearest')
                  for df in df_tomatch_list])

# ensure there is at least one match
m = mask.any(0)

# get first df number / index
i = np.argmax(mask, axis=0)
v = idxs[i, np.arange(len(time_tomatch))]

# combine, set to -1 if no match was found in any df
out = list(zip(np.where(m, i, -1), 
               np.where(m, v, -1)))

Output:
[(0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 2)]


Based on your get_indexer method :
def default_idx(df):
    return df.set_index(
        pd.Series(range(len(df))), append=True)

dfs = [df_tomatch_1, df_tomatch_2]

df = pd.concat(map(default_idx, dfs), keys=range(len(dfs)))
    
matches = (pd.to_datetime(df.index.get_level_values(1))
               .get_indexer(time_tomatch, method="nearest"))

Output shows :
df.iloc[matches].index
# MultiIndex([(0, '2023-01-01 11:00', 1),
#             (0, '2023-01-01 13:00', 3),
#             (1, '2023-01-02 12:00', 2)],
#            )

df.iloc[matches].index.droplevel(1).tolist() # OP's expected output
# [(0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 2)]

Hope this helps.If not please let me know.

NIrmal Really  thanks .This really solve my issue.

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree

# Create small DataFrames with datetime indexes
df_tomatch_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, index=pd.to_datetime([
    '1990-01-01 10:00',
    '1990-01-01 11:00',
    '1990-01-01 12:00',
    '1990-01-01 13:00'
]))

df_tomatch_2 = pd.DataFrame({'c': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, index=pd.to_datetime([
    '1990-01-02 10:00', 
    '1990-01-02 11:00', 
    '1990-01-02 12:00', 
    '1990-01-02 13:00'
]))

# List of dates to match
time_tomatch = pd.to_datetime([
    '1990-01-01 10:30',
    '1990-01-01 12:30',
    '1990-01-02 11:30'
])

def find_closest_matches(df):
  X = df.index.hour * 3600 + df.index.minute * 60
  X = X.values.reshape(-1,1)
  tree = BallTree(X)

  query_pts = time_tomatch.hour * 3600 + time_tomatch.minute * 60
  query_pts = query_pts.values.reshape(-1,1)

  dist, indices = tree.query(query_pts, k=1)
  closest_matches = df.iloc[indices.flatten()]
  return closest_matches

# Find closest matches for each DataFrame
closest_matches_1 = find_closest_matches(df_tomatch_1)
closest_matches_2 = find_closest_matches(df_tomatch_2)

# Concatenate results
combined_results = pd.concat([closest_matches_1, closest_matches_2], axis=1)
print(combined_results)
'''
                       a    c
1990-01-01 10:00:00  1.0  NaN
1990-01-01 11:00:00  2.0  NaN
1990-01-01 12:00:00  3.0  NaN
1990-01-02 10:00:00  NaN  1.0
1990-01-02 11:00:00  NaN  2.0
1990-01-02 12:00:00  NaN  3.0
'''

code 1 :
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree

# Create small DataFrames with datetime indexes
df_tomatch_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, index=pd.to_datetime([
    '2023-01-01 10:00',
    '2023-01-01 11:00',
    '2023-01-01 12:00',
    '2023-01-01 13:00'
]))

df_tomatch_2 = pd.DataFrame({'c': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, index=pd.to_datetime([
    '2023-01-02 10:00',
    '2023-01-02 11:00',
    '2023-01-02 12:00',
    '2023-01-02 13:00'
]))

df_tomatch_list = [df_tomatch_1, df_tomatch_2]

# List of dates to match
time_tomatch = pd.to_datetime([
    '2023-01-01 10:30',
    '2023-01-01 12:30',
    '2023-01-02 11:30'
])

# Convert datetime index and query times to seconds since epoch for numeric computation
def convert_to_seconds(dt_index):
    return dt_index.astype(np.int64) // 10**9 

# Convert all indexes to seconds and concatenate
all_indexes = [convert_to_seconds(df.index) for df in df_tomatch_list]
all_seconds = np.concatenate(all_indexes)

# Create index data array
index_data = np.concatenate([np.full(len(df), i) for i, df in enumerate(df_tomatch_list)])

# Create BallTree for efficient nearest-neighbor search
tree_data = all_seconds.reshape(-1, 1)
ball_tree = BallTree(tree_data, metric='euclidean')

# Convert query points to seconds since epoch
query_points = convert_to_seconds(time_tomatch).to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)

# Perform nearest-neighbor search
distances, indices = ball_tree.query(query_points, k=1)

# Flatten indices for easier handling
indices = indices.flatten()

# Determine the DataFrame boundaries
cumulative_lengths = np.cumsum([len(df) for df in df_tomatch_list])
df_indices = np.searchsorted(cumulative_lengths, indices, side='right')

# Calculate the positions within each DataFrame
positions_within_df = indices - np.concatenate(([0], cumulative_lengths[:-1]))[df_indices]

# Combine results
closest_matches = list(zip(df_indices, positions_within_df))

# Print combined results
print(closest_matches)
# [(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 1)]

code 2 :
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree

# Create small DataFrames with datetime indexes
df_tomatch_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, index=pd.to_datetime([
    '2023-01-01 10:00',
    '2023-01-01 11:00',
    '2023-01-01 12:00',
    '2023-01-01 13:00'
]))

df_tomatch_2 = pd.DataFrame({'c': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, index=pd.to_datetime([
    '2023-01-02 10:00',
    '2023-01-02 11:00',
    '2023-01-02 12:00',
    '2023-01-02 13:00'
]))

# List of dates to match
time_tomatch = pd.to_datetime([
    '2023-01-01 10:30',
    '2023-01-01 12:30',
    '2023-01-02 11:30'
])

# Convert datetime index and query times to seconds since epoch for numeric computation
def convert_to_seconds(dt_index):
    return dt_index.astype(np.int64) // 10**9

# Convert all indexes to seconds and concatenate
seconds_1 = convert_to_seconds(df_tomatch_1.index)
seconds_2 = convert_to_seconds(df_tomatch_2.index)

all_seconds = np.concatenate([seconds_1, seconds_2])

# Create index data array
index_data_1 = np.full(len(seconds_1), 0)
index_data_2 = np.full(len(seconds_2), 1)
index_data = np.concatenate([index_data_1, index_data_2])

# Reshape data for BallTree
tree_data = all_seconds.reshape(-1, 1)

# Create BallTree for efficient nearest-neighbor search
ball_tree = BallTree(tree_data, metric='euclidean')

# Convert query points to seconds since epoch
query_points = convert_to_seconds(time_tomatch).to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)

# Perform nearest-neighbor search
distances, indices = ball_tree.query(query_points, k=1)

# Compute cumulative lengths
cumulative_lengths = np.concatenate([[0], np.cumsum([len(df_tomatch_1), len(df_tomatch_2)])])
print(cumulative_lengths )
# Calculate the DataFrame index and position within each DataFrame
df_indices = index_data[indices.flatten()]
df_positions = indices.flatten() - cumulative_lengths[df_indices]
print(df_positions)
# Combine results
closest_matches = list(zip(df_indices, df_positions))

# Print combined results
print(closest_matches)
#[(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 1)]

